# Excel File Error After Download in C# Using NPOI

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, export-to-excel, npoi

I have an excel file template, and then add dropdown data to excel using C#, everthing is fine in my local machine, i can download it but when i put it in server is always getting error

[image]

[image]

and actually, this error file still can be used, but its really annoying especially for user

i,m using NPOI for processing this excel file

```
XSSFWorkbook hssfwb;

string path = Server.MapPath("~/Content/Uploads").ToString() + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PathAllocationRuleTemplate"].ToString();
            string newpath = Server.MapPath("~/Content/Uploads").ToString() + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PathAllocationRule"].ToString();


using (FileStream file = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                hssfwb = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
                file.Close();
            }


> some code for filling data


**downloading part**

using (FileStream file = new FileStream(newpath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                hssfwb.Write(file);
                file.Close();
            }

            System.Web.HttpResponse response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
            response.ClearContent();
            response.Clear();
            response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
            response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Allocation Rule Template.xlsx");
            response.TransmitFile(newpath);
            response.Buffer = true;
            response.Flush();            
            response.End();
```

Comment: `response.ContentType = "text/plain"` looks wrong to me. An xlsx file *isn't* plain text - why are you suggesting it is?

Comment: sorry, forgot to edit, i actually set contenttype = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" before, but i,m just trying change it to "text/plain", apparently, still not work in server, but in local is totally fine


is there any some error related to network or something ?

Comment: You should compare the file after downloading with the original file. Are they the same size? Have you looked at them in a binary file comparison tool?

Comment: "sorry, forgot to edit" - so please edit the question now. (And add the information about any comparisons you've made.)